# Is there to read the data from google spreadsheet link in IOS?

Tags: google-sheets-api

i am currently work on an IOS project which is required to read data from Spreadsheet in google drive. I have done some research and i found Google APIs client library for Objective C. However, i still have problem of retrieving data from spreadsheet. i find only the sample code that can read the file in drive from the drive that user login. But what i actually want in this project is using Google Drive as the Database. In short i want to retrieve data from the url like this https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AoYC7S60-ywcdHVZYzh4ZlZ1Y3J5R2ZGbnBqY09jdkE&usp=sharing.
So is there a solution for this kind of problem? and if there a good site that provide a good tutorial to this kindda problem?

Answer (score 0):

Google apps script is probably a simpler option. You can set it up as a web app, and read/write to the spreadsheet via the webapp. The google-spreadsheet-api is hard to use as there is little good documentation.

Comment: Read as CSV? You can grab areas of the sheet as csv, but is read only and public.

Comment: Yes, it requires me to read the data from CSV, but finally i didn't use the google-API. It's hard to use as you said there's little documentation and what i see is other language base like C#, Java. However, i'am currently using CSV reader from that url.

Answer (score 0):

Refer, [Google's Sample Code](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Examples/SpreadsheetSample) it can help you. You can also use [GData Objective C Client](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/) to use it.